# How to uniquely identify queries?

Tags: wp-query, query, pre-get-posts

Today I was thinking about how to differentiate queries, mainly to create an unique identifier. In the process I played around a bit, see below code.

The main idea is to do it depending on the `$query` or `$query_vars` property of `WP_Query`. There is actually already a property `query_vars_hash`, but it's created fairly early with a subset of the vars and isn't of help to distinguish queries that happen on the same request.

The following is what I have so far:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'unique_query' );
/**
 * unique_query
 *
 * Create unique identifier
 *
 */
function unique_query( $query ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $query_hashes = array();

    if ( is_admin() ) return;

    /**
     * Skip additional cases
     */
    /**
    if ( ! isset( $query->query['post_type'] )
        || empty( $query->query['post_type'] )
        || $query->query['post_type'] == 'nav_menu_item'
        || $query->is_main_query()
    ) {
        return;
    }
    /**/

    /**
     * Debug stuff
     */
    /**
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r( $query );
        print_r( $wp_query );
        print_r( $query->query );
        print_r( $wp_query->query );
        print_r( $query->query_vars );
        print_r( $wp_query->query_vars );
    echo '</pre>';
    /**/

    /**
     * Setup query hashes array
     */
    $query_hashes[ '$wp_query->query_vars_hash' ]  = $wp_query->query_vars_hash;
    $query_hashes[ 'uhash_$wp_query->query_vars' ] = md5( serialize( $wp_query->query_vars ) );
    $query_hashes[ '$query->query_vars_hash' ]     = $query->query_vars_hash;
    $query_hashes[ 'uhash_$query->query_vars' ]    = md5( serialize( $query->query_vars ) );
    $query_hashes[ 'uhash_$query->query' ]         = md5( serialize( $query->query ) );
    $query_hashes[ 'uhash_$wp_query->query' ]      = md5( serialize( $wp_query->query ) );

    /**
     * Print query hashes array
     */
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r( $query_hashes );
    echo '</pre>';

}
```

Which produces the following exemplary output:

```
/* Main query */
[$wp_query->query_vars_hash]  => ffb3c63f9b858ab4882d8e9ed20fce67
[uhash_$wp_query->query_vars] => ffb3c63f9b858ab4882d8e9ed20fce67
[$query->query_vars_hash]     => ffb3c63f9b858ab4882d8e9ed20fce67
[uhash_$query->query_vars]    => ffb3c63f9b858ab4882d8e9ed20fce67
[uhash_$query->query]         => 40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a
[uhash_$wp_query->query]      => 40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a

/* Query of wp_nav_menu */
[$wp_query->query_vars_hash]  => ffb3c63f9b858ab4882d8e9ed20fce67
[uhash_$wp_query->query_vars] => 59e1dad0ba690eed5e758fbf15cda702
[$query->query_vars_hash]     => c5a049c558df9cf4cfd14dad179a97e8
[uhash_$query->query_vars]    => c5a049c558df9cf4cfd14dad179a97e8
[uhash_$query->query]         => d4226d11be5a53e8b44d5b85db43e8b0
[uhash_$wp_query->query]      => 40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a

/* Front/home query */
[$wp_query->query_vars_hash]  => ffb3c63f9b858ab4882d8e9ed20fce67
[uhash_$wp_query->query_vars] => 59e1dad0ba690eed5e758fbf15cda702
[$query->query_vars_hash]     => 712b303f79eef3c8b5928d4ed8acfe2f
[uhash_$query->query_vars]    => 712b303f79eef3c8b5928d4ed8acfe2f
[uhash_$query->query]         => b7ac5bdfe084209f0142d7ab3aa0683e
[uhash_$wp_query->query]      => 40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a
```

As you can see the only candidates for a distinct determination are `$query->query_vars_hash`/`uhash_$query->query_vars` or `uhash_$query->query`. Of course in this example the first and second one are the same, but in the future there might be the need to do things not covered by the existing `query_vars_hash` property. Besides you have to do it yourself to be sure.

So the question would be, firstly, *is this a reasonable approach to uniquely identify queries?* Or am I missing something, especially, is there maybe a better one, so, secondly, if someone has input, I'm interested.

---

**Edit:**

@G.M. is pretty much right about everything that was implied with the problem raised. I actually had in mind to add this information, just hadn't enough time at the time posting, now it would just be redundant, but I wanted to confirm the fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr**: build affordable unique identifiers for queries is possible, but is pretty useless.

---

If you're looking for unique identifiers for query *objects*, then you can use [`spl_object_hash`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php), but IMHO is pretty useless: it is non-predictable, and also you get different id even if query vars are identical, but set on 2 different query objects.
Only reason to use it can be obtain a statistic like: *"During this request XX different `WP_Query` objects were instantiated."*

If you pointed your attention to query *variables* is probably because you are looking an id to identify query *results*, i.e. when you can obtain the same id from 2 different query objects then the results should be the same for both queries.

In that case I've a bad surprise for you: that will never happen, because no matter the technique you use, if you build your query id based on query vars you don't take into account `'posts_*'` filters ('posts_where', 'posts_join' and so on, they are 19 IIRC).

Proof of concept:

```
$query1 = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post' );

add_filter( 'posts_where', function() { return ' AND 1 = 0'; } );

$query2 = new WP_Query( 'post_type=post' );
```

`$query1` and `$query2` are identical, so a virtual callback returning an unique id based on query vars will return identical id for the 2 queries, but first query returns all published posts, second query returns nothing.

This is the reason why query vars are not a good starting point to build unique query id.

If what matters is query results, you should concentrate on query sql request: when request is the same results will be the same, in addition request is a string, so easily hashable.

A good candidate hook for the scope should be one when the request is completely built, but not yet performed, ['split_the_query'](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/c1e7c2d1de4a6a0d9c740761c426511bdbecbf5c/wp-includes/query.php#L3275) filter hook should be fine.

```
// prepare our ids storage
add_action( 'init', function() {
   global $query_ids;
   $query_ids = array();
});

// use the filter to build and store the id
add_filter( 'split_the_query', function( $split_the_query, $query ) {
  $hash = md5( $query->request );
  $hash .= $split_the_query ? '_split' : '';
  global $query_ids;
  if ( ! in_array( $hash, $query_ids, TRUE ) ) {
    $query_ids[] = $hash; // store hash if not already stored
  }
  return $split_the_query; // return $split_the_query as is
}, PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
```

Now, we have a way to build unique query identifiers: when we can obtain the same identifier from 2 queries, then results of the 2 queries are the same.

But what we can do with that? Maybe a statistic like:

```
add_action('shutdown', function() {
   global $query_ids;
   echo count( $query_ids ) . " different WP_Query requests were performed.";
});
```

I can't find what is the usefulness of a statistic like that, but maybe someone can.

I know you are thinking about to use the query identifier to *cache* the query, and don't trigger a database request when id is the same, and it's a good idea, but... you can't.

The problem is that when WordPress has built the request, then immediately runs it, giving you no chance to short-circuit it!

Or better, once WordPress uses `$wpdb->get_results` to perform the query, and once `$wpdb` is a global variable, a chance is to replace that object with a modified wpdb class capable of caching, it's a good idea, but in that case make no sense build an unique id for the queries once all the cache happen on `$wpdb` based on sql requests ran there.

In substance, problem is that WordPress suffers by 2 big problems regarding `WP_Query` logic (among others about `WP_Query` messy code):

1. process of *building* the query and process of *running* the query are not separable
2. there is no way to short-circuit the query: once `WP_Query::get_posts()` method has been called there is no way to prevent the sql query to be ran

Until those 2 issues stay there, IMHO create an unique id for queries is something that can be used only for eccentric statistics...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very informational, you filled pretty much all the gaps and BTW are right about all the implicit thoughts I had too.

Comment: I'm aware that there is a problem with the approach, because of all the `posts_*` filters. So this isn't something that can be done in a general environment, because - like you have shown - there is no possibility to control what will be done to the query after - supposedly - identifying it uniquely. But in my environment I'm - assumably - in total control; or at least can be. So I could potentially be able to actually know that a specific input of query variables leads to a according expected output. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Disregarding your valid objections furthermore, just another question for confirmation. I see there is no possibility for interception once the request has been started, but just theoretically intercepting should be possible at the `pre_get_posts` filter stage, right?

Comment: Another thought, what about additionally considering something like raised in this question: [replace the WP_Query class in the main query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/119063/22534).

Comment: BTW I'm going to award a bounty on this, not able yet though. Not because I'm not happy with your answer, on the contrary. But because I have all those additional counter questions and because I'm trying to get as much information as possible to learn more about it, I think it's the right thing to do.

Comment: @ialocin yours are good points, and I have something to say about, but I can't until friday because on travel. Just a quick note, replacing WP_Query class can be a solution, and it's one of the reasons I introduced [this feature in Cortex](http://cortex.zoomlab.it/docs/routes-basics.html#custom-wp_query-class)

Comment: No worries and no hurry, I have to put this on hold myself. For now, I'm going to be busy for awhile, probably coming back to this in July.