# How to detect custom query inside `posts_where` hook?

Tags: wp-query, query

Imagine you have something like this:

```
function f_posts_where( $where ){
// set a condition based on arguments ...    
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'f_posts_where' );
```

What is the best way to set a condition for my custom query inside the `f_posts_where`?

I create a custom query like this:

```
$q = new \WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we have the query arguments like this

```
$args = array(
  'queryid' => 'blackjack',
   ...    
);
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Note we added one custom query argument that is not officially present in [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).
Now we can identify the exact query by that `queryid` if we use the second parameter of the `posts_where` hook.

```
function f_posts_where( $where,  \WP_Query $q ){
  // $q->query will hold the query arguments ...
  if ( 'blackjack' == $q->query['queryid'] ){
    // do our custom actions on $where for our queryid blackjack
    return $where.
  }
 return $where;
}

add_filter( 'posts_where', 'f_posts_where', 10 , 2 );
```

As you can note `$q->query` will hold the query arguments.

This will allow us to intercept the custom queries we like if we add custom arguments we like. In this case the `queryid`.

Comment: yes custom query arguments can be handy. There's a getter for it `WP_Query::get()` so we could use `$q->get( 'queryid' )`. When I use it I sometimes prefix the arguments with `wpse_` or just underscore (e.g. [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/136758/26350)), to avoid possible name collision in the future.

Comment: @birgire: Maybe one-day query argument `_id` become part of the codex and part of the default query arguments.

Comment: Based on your idea, any query may have the `_id` for instance `main-search` may be one nice name.

Comment: I've learned a lot from this site, so I try to pass it on when I can ;-)  [Here's](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149578/how-to-uniquely-identify-queries) a discussion on the general automatic approach.

Comment: @birgire, I will that link.  The human readable names may be great when creating conditions for `posts_where` and several other hooks... But we are good.

Comment: I agree, I think they can be very helpful in that regard, [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/184396/26350) example just came to mind, as another context. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: Likewise, btw, I think I will propose these `_id` parameters and smarter conditions tips, after the weekend to WordPress track, and we will see.

Comment: ps: the problem might be though with such an official query var identifier is that it could be modified and not be trusted - but there are always pros and cons ;-) Maybe you can think of another possible approaches ;-)

Comment: Wow, thank you- this is the first I've heard of custom query arguments, and using a custom queryid to limit/scope a filter function is brilliant!